# Android how to start a new activity WHILE screen is locked?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have read threads on the matter but all of them were regarding launching an activity WHEN the screen is locked or when it is unlocked. However, I need for my program to launch a new activity regardless of the screen being locked or not.

I am using gps and proximity alerts to check when a destination has been reached. 
My activity registers a ProximityAlertReceiver such that:

```
private class ProximityAlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

        Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

        if (entering) {
            System.out.println("You have entered the proximity area");
        } else {
            System.out.println("You have exited the proximity area");
        }

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        int status = bundle.getInt("status");

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClass(context, MEcheScreen.class);
        Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
        bundle1.putInt("status", status);
        i.putExtras(bundle1);

        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        context.startActivity(i);



    }
}
```

So, when I a proximity alert fires, a new activity will be started.

I am using the `public void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent) {}` method to handle when the new activity is launched.

So, the problem is, when the screen is locked and a proximity alert is fired, the Intent in the ProximityAlertReceiver class does not get started.

I tried to use the keyguardmanager to disable the keyguard. However, after it has been disabled, it returns to the main screen of the program, but the activity is still not started until I press a button or tap the screen.

Comment: too late to check, did it work, my activity is called(since I set break point to check) but the screen is not on or the keypad is unlocked

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should fire a notification instead (with sounds and flashing lights even if necessary) from which the activity can be launched IF wanted by the user, which would seem the right thing to do..

Comment: No. The thing is, when a proximity region is reached, a proximity alert fires which creates a new activity. Then, this proximity alert is discarded and another one is created. This has to be done automatically by the program.

Answer (score 0):

a couple of things are needed ...

in your reciever add the following when launching the activity

```
intenet.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

in the onCreate of the activity add

```
KeyguardManager mKeyGuardManager = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(KEYGUARD_SERVICE); 
KeyguardLock mLock = mKeyGuardManager.newKeyguardLock("name of my app");  
mLock.disableKeyguard();
```

this works for me in an app that is lauched at device startup

I also then mess with

```
Settings.System.getInt(cr,Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT,0);
```

but that is another story

Comment: As i said in my question, I am already using the disableKeyguard() function. However, what happens is that the keyguard is disabled, fine, but when the screen goes dark(either by pressing the close button on the phone, or by passing some idle time) and when a the phone is in the proximity region, the activity does not start. It only starts when I make the phone active(by pressing any button). Adding the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag does not solve the problem and the activity is still not started.